# ¿Cómo puedo imprimir el número de bits establecidos en la representación binaria de un número?

Tags: java

Dado un número N, quiero imprimir el número de bits establecidos en la representación binaria de este número.

Entrada: El primero contiene un entero único T que denota el número de casos de prueba. Cada caso de prueba contiene un solo entero N

Salida: Para cada caso de prueba, imprima un entero único que denote el número de bits establecidos en la representación binaria de N.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y este es mi código actual:

```
import java.util.*;
public class Bit {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan=new Scanner (System.in);
    int inc=0;
    int cas=scan.nextInt();
    for(int k=0; k<cas; k++) 
    {
        int num=scan.nextInt();
        for(int iter=num; iter>0; iter=iter/2)
        {
            if(iter%2==1)
            {
                inc++;   
            }
        }
        System.out.println(inc);      
    }
}
```

}

Y estos son algunos resultados, en la primera imagen el resultado es correcto

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero en esta imagen, el resultado no es correcto.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De antemano muchas gracias y disculpen por mi torpeza.

Comment: Acabas de eliminar una pregunta similar a esta, con un monton de comentarios en la misma, donde se te estaban marcando algunos errores. El sitio no es para guiarte, si no para solucionar problemas concretos. Tu problema concreto es que la variable inc no se borra entre cada pedido de un numero.

Comment: Y como puedo hacer eso?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tu problema es que no limpias la variable inc, entre cada pedido de un numero, por lo cual estas sumando el resultado anterior al siguiente..

Tenes que agregar una limpieza de la variable `inc=0`

```
for(int k=0; k<cas; k++) 
{
    int num=scan.nextInt();
    for(int iter=num; iter>0; iter=iter/2)
    {
        if(iter%2==1)
        {
            inc++;   
        }
    }
    System.out.println(inc);     
    inc = 0; 
}
```

Comment: Gracias, tomare nota para que ya no me vuelva a ocurrir en algún futuro.